# AngularJS array to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, websocket, angularjs-ng-repeat

When a websocket message recieved the following code runs:

```
connection.onmessage = function (eventInfo) {
var onConnectionMessage = JSON.parse(eventInfo.data);

if (onConnectionMessage.messageType === "newRequest") {
    getQuizRequests();
}
}
```

getQuizRequests() is the following function:

```
function getQuizRequests() {
var URL = '/acceptOrReject/' + lookUpCode();

$http.get(URL)
    .success(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.teamArray.length; i++) {
            teamArray[0] = data.teamArray[i];
        }
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
        alert("ERROR data cant be loaded");
    });
 }
```

I want to call this teamArray in a ng-repeat. How can I send this array filled to the code where I use ng-repeat?

Comment: needs to be part of the controller scope that view renders. Where is `teamArray` defined? Why are you over writing `teamArray[0]` each time. Please provide all relevant code context

Comment: Is this code in a service? Controller?

Comment: `teamArray[0] = data.teamArray[i];` does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is all in the same controller

```
$scope.teamArray = [];

function getQuizRequests() {
    var URL = '/acceptOrReject/' + lookUpCode();

    $http.get(URL)
    .success(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.teamArray.length; i++) {
            $scope.teamArray.push(data.teamArray[i]);
        }
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
            alert("ERROR data cant be loaded");
    });
 }
```

Then in your html

```
<ul ng-show="teamArray.length > 0" ng-repeat="member in teamArray">
    <li>{{member}}</li>
</ul>
```